# Wordpress 6.4 Lock editing on all template files

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to lock all template files in Wordpress 6.4 so that the templates, and blocks within these templates cannot be edited. The 'edit' buttons remain on the blocks no matter what I try. I can 'lock' blocks but then someone can easily 'unlock' them or go into appearance>editor>templates and edit each block from here. What is the best way to lock-down all templates, so they can only be edited from the actual template files?